# ¿Cómo limpiar el contenido una variable en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito que mi pagina web ejecute funciones con teclas especificas del teclado valga la redundancia, lo que he hecho es esto:

```
function pulsar(event){   
      tecla = event.keyCode;   
      switch(tecla) {    
       case 27:   
       cerrar();  
        break  
        case 49:  
         leng();  
        break;  
       case 50:  
       mate();  
        break;  
         case 51:  
        exp();    
        break;   
         case 52:   
       des();     
        break;   
         case 53:   
        cie();   
        break;  
              }    
           }   
window.onkeydown=pulsar;
```

¿Cómo limpiar el contenido de la variable para poder volver a usarla?, en este caso la variable es ***tecla*** ya probe con ***tecla.length=0;*** pero no funcionó.

Comment: que estas usando js puro?, falta información podrias colocar tu html

Comment: Necesitás limpiar el contenido para hacer qué cosa?

Comment: probaste con un `tecla = null` ?

Comment: y con `tecla = null;` o `tecla = undefined;` sinceramente no se por qué intentaste con `tecla.length = 0`

Comment: para que quieres reutilizar una variable colocala let en cada una de las funciones creo que es mejor, hasta optimo

Comment: El porque de limpiar la variable, es porque tengo varios contenedores en mi web y quiero poder desplazarme entre ellos con las mismas teclas del keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente [hilo (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable), se habla de esto y como deshacer una variable, la explicación es amplia y explica como hacerlo con cada tipo de variables, en este caso debido a que la variable no se declara con ***var*** :

```
...
tecla = event.keyCode;
...
```

Esta puede ser borrada sin necesidad de colocar algo como `tecla = null` o `tecla = undefined` de la siguieente manera:

```
tecla = event.keyCode;
...
delete tecla;
//Puedes ver el resultado
console.log(tecla);
```

De esta manera no quedara rastro de esta variable, ¿Te ha resultado?

Comment: ciertamente usar `delete`es la forma correcta pero en cuanto a performance es mejor reasignar `undefined`, solo digo